# Distinct days using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of time sheet entries and usually each user will have multiple entries for the same day because they clock in and out during lunch.

My time sheet class looks like this:

```
public class TimeSheetEntry
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockInTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockOutTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I want to determine the number of days a user has worked. I want to do this using the `ClockInTimeStamp` property by counting the unique days in my `List<TimeSheetEntry>()`.

How do I get the number of unique days in this list using LINQ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the `Distinct` linq method? It comes as one of the top hits on google for "linq distinct" and I've a suspicion it might be useful for you...

Comment: Yes, I have but it's not returning accurate results. It may be due to the fact that I'm dealing with `DateTime` and not just date. I'm now trying it again by converting my `DateTime` values to `DateTime.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Date/Time math can get pretty ugly, especially in a situation like this. How are you defining a "day"? For example, if on the odd chance, someone clocks in at 1:00 AM on Feb 5, and clocks out at 9:00 AM on Feb 5. Then later clocks in at 12:00 PM on Feb 5 and clocks out at 8:00 PM on Feb 5. How many days is that? Is that even valid? Is it a single day with over time, or two shifts?

Comment: @SteveBrouillard You're exactly right about DateTime calculations. In order to keep it somewhat simple, I'm going by actual date and not paying any attention to time. So if the date is 2/20/2018, that's one day.

Comment: @Sam Check out the link in my answer, then.

Comment: Show us the code you have that isn't working and we can help you to fix it... `mydatetime.Date` might also be helpful...

Comment: @Chris Using only the `Date` part of `DateTime` solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: What if they clock in at 11pm and clock out at 4am? Is that one day or two?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why unit testing is so important. Besides making sure that the function works with a variety of inputs, it documents what the expected behavior is. I haven't done TDD, but in this case I can see the value of writing the tests first, including tests for all of these edge cases, and in the tests specifying what the result should be. That forces you to decide up front what behavior you want for all of those edge cases. It makes so much sense to do that and then write the method so that it fulfills the expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timesheetEntries
    .GroupBy( te => te.EmployeeId )
    .Select(
        grp => new {
            EmployeeId = grp.Key,
            DayCount = grp
                .Select( te => te.ClockInTimeStamp.Date )
                .Distinct()
                .Count()
        }
    )
    .ToDictionary(
        t => t.EmployeeId,
        t => t.DayCount
    );
```

I realise the intermediate `Select` can be elided:

```
timesheetEntries
    .GroupBy( te => te.EmployeeId )
    .ToDictionary(
        grp => grp.Key /* EmployeeId */,
        grp => grp
            .Select( te => te.ClockInTimeStamp.Date )
            .Distinct()
            .Count()
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for counting strictly dates, without regard to time? If so, you may want to look at changing the two DateTime property types and use the [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) library, which has date only types.

Given your response to my comment on your OP, I would strongly recommend getting away from DateTime and looking at Noda Time.

Comment: For this particular situation this seems a little overkill as ignoring the time portion is trivial without adding an extra dependency. However, it's obvious he's working with timesheets and will be facing more than just this problem so it's still applicable.

Comment: @McAden. That's ultimately my point. The question behind the question is more complex.

Comment: @MickyD. I'm not suggest he role his own. I'm suggesting he use a library built by an acknowledged C# and DateTime/Time Zone expert.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).  A _timesheet_ app that ignores time, that just seems silly to me.  Then again I'm no expert

Comment: @MickyD.I don't have an issue with a critique of my answer in the context of whether you think it addresses the issue or not. I would say, however, that if you look at the comments on the OP, you'd see that this answer was as a result of just such a thread. What I do have an issue with is that you made an assertion regarding my comment about the library author being an expert without actually knowing who the author was. I agree that a timesheet app that ignores actual time is silly. I was trying to balance getting at the core of the issue with providing an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

.Distinct() is probably what you're looking for. You simply have to specify which property you're filtering by Distinct() on.

```
int numberOfDaysWorked = fullCollection.Select(x => x.ClockInTimeStamp).Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not getting distinct on the DateTime because of the time portion. You should be able to get that by specifically getting the `DateTime.Date` with something like this:

```
context.TimeSheetEntries.Select(e => e.ClockInTimeStamp.Date).Distinct();
```

Note if this is LINQ pulling directly from sql via EF you may have some issue with the ".Date" part so you may have to force the collection to enumerate at some point before that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two details I don't see accounted for in the other answers:

1. What if the user clocks in on one day and clocks out the next day? That's two days.
2. What if the user clocks in and clocks out several days later? I'm sure that shouldn't happen, but what if it does? I'm sure you want some way to ensure that employees don't stay clocked in for five days, but a function that returns the wrong result won't accomplish that. You can check for that somewhere else.

For this reason I recommend starting with a separate function so that it's possible to unit test it with various inputs. Writing unit tests will allow you to "fake" various combinations of entries, think through what you want the result to be, test to determine whether the function outputs what you expect, and then easily debug to find out why it doesn't.

Here's one approach. Since any individual date may be repeated (there could be any number of timestamps for a given date), I'm just adding them to a `HashSet<DateTime>` which will eliminate duplicates.

Then, if there is at least one full day between the start and end date, loop through the dates in the range and add all of them.

```
public static class TimeSheetCalculations
{
    public static int CalculateDistinctDays(this IEnumerable<TimeSheetEntry> entries)
    {
        var uniqueDays = new HashSet<DateTime>();
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var clockInDate = entry.ClockInTimeStamp.Date;
            var clockOutDate = entry.ClockOutTimeStamp.Date;
            uniqueDays.Add(clockInDate);
            uniqueDays.Add(clockOutDate);
            var totalDays = (clockOutDate - clockInDate).TotalDays;
            if (totalDays < 2) continue;
            for (var x = 1; x < totalDays; x++)
            {
                uniqueDays.Add(clockInDate.AddDays(x));
            }
        }
        return uniqueDays.Count;
    }
}
```

(I don't usually go with `static` methods, but in this case it seems harmless.)

Now that the method is isolated, it's easy to write some tests. I wrote one:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CalculatesCorrectDistinctDaysWorked()
    {
        var timesheetEntries = new TimeSheetEntry[]
        {
            new TimeSheetEntry
            {
                ClockInTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018 11:50PM"),
                ClockOutTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/5/2018 1:00AM")
            },
            new TimeSheetEntry
            {
                ClockInTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/5/2018 1:00PM"),
                ClockOutTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/5/2018 9:00PM")
            },
            new TimeSheetEntry
            {
                ClockInTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/6/2018 1:00PM"),
                ClockOutTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("1/7/2018 9:00PM")
            },
        };
        var daysWorked = timesheetEntries.CalculateDistinctDays();
        Assert.AreEqual(7, daysWorked);
    }
}
```

If someone punched in one 1/1, punched out on 1/5, in and out again on 1/5, in on 1/6, and out on 1/7, then that's seven days, even though they never punched in or out on 1/2, 1/3, or 1/4.

The unit test confirms the expected result.

One other error condition I'd check for is to confirm that the clockout is after the clockin. But I wouldn't do that here. I'd validate that entry somewhere else (you probably already are.)